# No longer Earning Rep for Edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I am no longer earning reputation for approved edits.

- What is happening?
- Has the rules changed?

I have had a few edits approved, but my rep has still stayed the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You gain reputation when:
>
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)

According to [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/522665):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SuggestedEdits WHERE OwnerUserId = 20752 AND ApprovalDate IS NOT NULL;
```

You've had 614 approved edits, so you're probably at the cap